Iterate over types exported in a barrel file
How can I iterate over exported types in a barrel?

Here I'd like Key to be any of the exported type names in seeds.
And I would like to be able to access types by name from a barrel import.
If I use keyof typeof seeds, it's stripping out all the types in seeds
Is it even possible?
For instance, with these files:
types.ts
export type TypeA = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

export type TypeB = {
  c: number;
  d: string;
}

index.ts
import * as types from './types';

type MyType = Partial<{
  [Key in keyof types]: types[Key][];
}>;

I'd like MyType to be
type MyType = Partial<{
  "TypeA": TypeA[];
  "TypeB": TypeB[]
}>;


Typescript is duck typed (or structurally typed if you will), the type names don't exist as far as the types themselves are concerned.

It's not possible. The usual approach would be to include all your types from types.ts in an interface, eventually with a default export:
export default interface Types {
    TypeA: {
        a: number;
        b: string;
    }
    
    TypeB: {
        c: number;
        d: string;
    }
}

You can then do what you were looking to:
import type Types from './types';

type MyType = Partial<{
    [Key in keyof Types]: Types[Key][];
}>;


Yes, I wrote in my question that unfortunately, typeof of an import is somehow stripping all the types of that import away. So I'm looking for an other way than doing typeof types

@AlexandreDaubricourt Oh, I understand, thanks for the clarification. I've edited my answer.

I was looking for a way to avoid redeclaring everything again in the barrel file, I've gone a similar way, but I'm not entirely satisfied with TS limitations.. import { SequelizeMeta } from './SequelizeMeta'; export type Models = { SequelizeMeta: SequelizeMeta; ... }
